# Plugin widget, include file extension by default

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I've got a Plugin widget box I'm trying to configure. In one step the user defines the path to where they will export the final layout as a .pdf file. I'm using the following code to configure the box:

```
class CreatePrintLayoutAndExportMap(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    OUTPUT_PDF_PATH = 'OUTPUT_PDF_PATH'
    OUTPUT_PDF_FILENAME_DEFAULT = 'Choose file path for pdf output'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config):

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(
                self.OUTPUT_PDF_PATH,
                self.tr(self.OUTPUT_PDF_FILENAME_DEFAULT),
                ".pdf"))
```

Here is what the box looks like as a GUI tool:
[image]

This is good. The issue here is when a user specifies the destination, the file extension is not included and they must type "...filename.pdf" and the file extension is not manually included. Here is what it looks like in action:
[image]

and then back in the widget box. Notice the .pdf file extension is not included automatically:
[image]

If I run the tool, the file is saved as some weird file with no file type. If I explicitly include .pdf at the end of the filename (ex: "...filename.pdf"), I get a .pdf file

I've been looking at documentation for [QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingParameterFileDestination.html) as well as for [QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination.html) as a comparison. The interesting thing is that if I export a raster file using the RasterDestination class, the .tif file extension is automatically included, removing confusion for the user.

Here is an example of a Raster output. I did not have to manually type '.tif' for it to be included:
[image]

Is there a way to automatically include a file extension when using QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination class?

Comment: Perhaps a platform issue? On a Windows machine, the `.pdf` is automatically appended to the file path entered.

Comment: Thanks Joseph.  I'll test on a PC

Comment: @Joseph after testing, you are right. The file path is automatically included on a PC. This is annoying but I can work with it.